# Android KeyStore crashes in Android Instant App

Tags: kotlin, encryption, keystore, android-keystore, android-instant-apps

```
val masterKey =
            MasterKey
            .Builder(applicationContext)
            .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
            .build()
```

Running this code in an Instant App crashes my app with the following Stack Trace:

```
2020-12-21 13:07:29.654 28949-28949/com.example.instantappandroidkeystore E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.instantappandroidkeystore, PID: 28949
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.instantappandroidkeystore/com.example.instantappandroidkeystore.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.security.keystore.IKeystoreService.exist(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.security.keystore.IKeystoreService.exist(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.security.KeyStore.contains(KeyStore.java:408)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.engineContainsAlias(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:1038)
        at java.security.KeyStore.containsAlias(KeyStore.java:1293)
        at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.keyExists(MasterKeys.java:154)
        at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.java:96)
        at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKey$Builder.buildOnM(MasterKey.java:357)
        at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKey$Builder.build(MasterKey.java:314)
        at com.example.instantappandroidkeystore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

I have no luck finding this issue in StackOverflow, but I have found it in Google Issue Tracker, but with no response. So I created submitted an issue to Google with more information. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176085956

Has anyone encounter this issue and was able to solve it.

My working environment is:

- Mac OS 10.15.7
- Android Studio 4.0.1
- Samsung A70
- Android version 10

Answer (score 4):

While this is not documented formally on developer.android forum, looks like AndroidKeyStore access is restricted for instant apps. I came across this link https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7a4tdw/why_no_hardware_backed_keystore_in_instant_apps/

This is quite strange that keystore is restricted and no android documentation explains it. I am not sure on an alternative to accessing KeyStore as we have lot of dependency on keystore for our regular app (non instant) and I can't think of a better option. Looking forward for suggestions !